# SQL: Refactoring a multi-join query

Tags: mysql, database

I have a query that should be quite simple and yet it causes me a lot of headaches. 
I have a simple ads system that requires filtering ads according to a few variables.
I need to limit the number of views/clicks per day and the total number of views/clicks for a given ad. Also each ad is linked to one or more slots in which the ad can appear. I have a table that saves the statistics that I need about each ad. Note that the statistics table changes very frequently.
These are the tables that I'm using:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_ads` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL,
  `max_views` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `refresh` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `max_clicks` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `max_daily_clicks` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `max_daily_views` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `t_ad_slots` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment ,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `width` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `height` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `t_ads_to_slots` (
  `ad_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `slot_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ad_id`,`slot_id`),
  KEY `slot_id` (`slot_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `t_ads_to_slots`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `t_ads_to_slots_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ad_id`) REFERENCES `t_ads` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `t_ads_to_slots_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`slot_id`) REFERENCES `t_ad_slots` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

CREATE TABLE `t_ad_stats` (
  `ad_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `slot_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL COMMENT,
  `views` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `unique_views` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `clicks` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ad_id`,`slot_id`,`date`),
  KEY `slot_id` (`slot_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `t_ad_stats`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `t_ad_stats_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ad_id`) REFERENCES `t_ads` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `t_ad_stats_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`slot_id`) REFERENCES `t_ad_slots` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

This is the query that I use to get ads for a given slot (Note that in this example I hard coded 20 as the slot id and 0,1,2 as the ad type, I get this data from a php script which invokes this query)

```
SELECT      `ads`.`content`, `slots`.`value`, `ads`.`id`, `ads`.`refresh`, `ads`.`type`,
            SUM(`total_stats`.`views`) AS "total_views",
            SUM(`total_stats`.`clicks`) AS "total_clicks"
FROM        (`t_ads` AS `ads`,
            `t_ads_to_slots` AS `slots`)
LEFT JOIN   `t_ad_stats` AS `total_stats`
ON          `total_stats`.`ad_id` = `ads`.`id`
LEFT JOIN   `t_ad_stats` AS `daily_stats`
ON          (`daily_stats`.`ad_id` = `ads`.`id`)    AND
            (`daily_stats`.`date` = CURDATE())
WHERE       (`ads`.`id` = `slots`.`ad_id`)          AND
            (`ads`.`type` IN(0,1,2))                    AND
            (`slots`.`slot_id` = 20)                AND
            (`ads`.`is_active` = 1)                 AND
            (`ads`.`end_date` >= NOW())             AND
            (`ads`.`start_date` <= NOW())           AND
            ((`ads`.`max_views` = 0) OR
             (`ads`.`max_views` > "total_views"))   AND
            ((`ads`.`max_clicks` = 0) OR
             (`ads`.`max_clicks` > "total_clicks")) AND
            ((`ads`.`max_daily_clicks` = 0) OR
             (`ads`.`max_daily_clicks` > IFNULL(`daily_stats`.`clicks`,0))) AND
            ((`ads`.`max_daily_views` = 0) OR
             (`ads`.`max_daily_views` > IFNULL(`daily_stats`.`views`,0)))
GROUP BY    (`ads`.`id`)
```

I believe that this query is self explanatory, even though its quite long. Note that the MySQL version that I'm using is: 5.0.51a-community. It seems to me like the big issue here is the double join to the stats table (I did that so that I will be able to get the data from a specific record and from multiple records (sum)).

How would you implement this query in order to get better results? (Note that I can't change from InnoDB).

Hopefully everything is clear about my question, but if that is not the case, please ask and I will clarify.
Thanks in advance,
Kfir

Comment: What is the cause of the headache exactly? I would assume performance but... please clarify.

Comment: As an aside its hard to read SQL when you mix ANSI-86 and ANSI-92 style joins. You might as well make  `(ads.id = slots.ad_id)` an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Attempting to run this query should actually result in an error. Your GROUP BY lists ads.id but your SELECT lists 4 additional non-aggregate fields.

Comment: @Paul Sasik: mysql forgives such inconsistencies :-) Yes, I wish it didn't too

Comment: @PaulSasik Yep, the problem is a performance issue.
ConradFrix Noted, will apply that to future queries.
MarcusAdams The performance of this query is not as good as I would like. It causes a heavy load on my server as it is executed quite a lot of times (about 1~2 times per user, depending on how many ad slots are the viewed page). So better result would be lower retrieval time
As for the issue that Paul raised about my use of group by I would to say that I just executed it again and it is valid query. Do you have a better suggestion as to how I should group the results from the stats table?

Comment: Well it looks horrible, but I can't see lot of value in changing it except cosmetic stuff. Is it slow?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Well it is not as fast as I wish it would be.. aside from that, what "cosmetic stuff" would you change?

Comment: @kfir: There are a lot of predicates in your WHERE clause. You should have most of these, perhaps all indexed. Can you verify which of the referenced columns are indexed, if any? If few or none, then that's the place to start. Apply indexing!

Comment: Does this query run without error? As it is? And are you sure it produces what you intend to?

Comment: Using `"total_views"` and `"total_clicks"` in the `WHERE` condition seems totally circular logic. It should result in either an error or MySQL misinterprets these two "columns".

Comment: @ypercube As far as I tested this query works properly.. can you give me an example as to when this query will not retrieve the data I expected? (not passing all the checks I placed in the where clause).

Answer (score 0):

Add indexes to following columns:

```
t_ads.is_active
t_ads.start_date
t_ads.end_date
```

Change the order of the primary key on t_ad_stats to:

```
(`ad_id`,`date`,`slot_id`)
```

or add a covering index to t_ad_stats

```
('ad_id', 'date')
```

Change from `0` meaning "no limit" to `2147483647` meaning no limit, so you can change things like:

```
((`ads`.`max_views` = 0) OR (`ads`.`max_views` > "total_views"))
```

to

```
(`ads`.`max_views` > "total_views")
```

You could greatly improve this is if you were keeping running totals instead of having to calculate them each time.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on a comment above I believe that the following columns should be indexed:

```
ads.id
ads.type
ads.start_date
ads.end_date
daily_stats.date
```

As well as these:

```
slots.slot_id
ads.is_active
```

And these as well:

```
ads.max_views
ads.max_clicks
ads.max_daily_clicks
ads.max_daily_views
daily_stats.clicks
daily_stats.views
```

Do note that applying indexes on these columns will speed up your SELECTs but slow down your INSERTs since the indexes will need updating as well. But, you don't have to apply all of this all at once. You can do it incrementally and see how the performance shakes out for selects as well as inserts. If you cannot find a good middleground then I would suggest denormalization.